# Integration problem: $\int _ {-\infty} ^ {\infty} \frac {e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^x\ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, numerical-methods, improper-integrals

I have to integrate

$$\int _ {-\infty} ^ {\infty} \frac {e^{\large-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{\large x}\ dx.$$

I've already done by numerical approximations, like Simpson's rule and Gauss-Hermite, but I need the analytical way to do it, and I'm seriously running out of ideas. If someone could help me, it would be great. Thanks so much! And please, if you do not understand something from the question, just ask me, please. Thanks again!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why did you edit again all my editing? Is that something wrong with that? Please let me know if any.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: Yes, don't use `displaystyle` in titles.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why? It looks nicer to me using that. It is a matter of taste between us or there is a rule about restriction of    displaystyle usage in the title?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: It breaks the front page.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us use that we do know the value if $e^{-x^2}$ is the only thing in the integral.

Then we could complete the square in the exponent and translate the variable.

This is: The $\sqrt{\pi}$ factor is irrelevant; we can take it out of the integral.

Then is only $e^{-x^2+x}=e^{-(x^2-x)}=e^{-[(x-1/2)^2+1/4]}=e^{-1/4}e^{-(x-1/2)^2}$.

The factor $e^{-1/4}$ can be taken out of the integral. And change variable $y=x-1/2$.

You will get the integral of $e^{-x^2}$. Do you know the value of this one and how to get it?

Comment: Yes, I do, thanks so much! It was really helpful :)

Comment: Although now that you mentioned it, do you know how to do it without using Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @LunaSage Can I use complex numbers? The other way I know is using integration of path integrals. I guess the complex integration can always be painfully translated into a completely real-value tour de force.

Comment: You can find in Wikipedia yet [another way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_Cartesian_coordinates).

Comment: Yes, of course. Maybe the way of translate it is using polar coordinates, which I'm not a fan of, but sometimes they are quite useful...

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out. Thanks for your help. And I'm really sorry for my spelling :)

Comment: Oops, actually that was the way I knew! That was the one I had in mind when you mentioned Fubini. Now I see there the one that uses Fubini is one that, althought I have seen before, I usually don't have it in mind when I look at this integral.

Comment: It's an interesting proof actually, but not the easiest one, and I needed a quick one so I could go on with the excercise. You were really helpful, thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{x}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-((x-\frac{1}{2})^{2}-\frac{1}{4})}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{}\pi}e^{\frac{1}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x-\frac{1}{2})^{2}}dx$$

Comment: You're welcome. Hope that helped.